# Switch Case in T-SQL In where Clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why this doesn't work? Please help.

```
SELECT X 
FROM Y
WHERE Z >= 5
  AND A IN (CASE @someParameter when 1 THEN (5) ELSE (4,5) END)
```

Where as below works

```
SELECT X 
FROM Y
WHERE Z >= 5
  AND A = (CASE @someParameter when 1 THEN 5 ELSE 4 END)
```

Comment: What is the comma doing there in `(4,5)`?

Comment: You may want to observe that `IN` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish that without `case`, like:

```
WHERE Z >= 5
  AND (
      @SomeParameter = 1 AND A = 5
      OR 
      @SomeParameter <> 1 AND A IN (4,5)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have select statement instead of mentioning numbers directly. I ahven't tried executing it. But the idea is to get the required number set by using select query inside your brackets.

```
SELECT X  
FROM Y 
WHERE Z >= 5   
AND A IN (CASE @someParameter when 1 THEN (SELECT 4) ELSE (SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a *set*, range, or table (or anything else you want to call multiple values) from a CASE statement.  That `(4,5)` expression is just not allowed.  My advice instead is to build these values as a small lookup table you can select from.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X 
FROM Y
WHERE Z >= 5
  AND 
  CASE @someParameter 
  when 1 THEN A = 5 
  ELSE (A = 4 OR A = 5)
  END
```

Note: I haven't tried this syntax. My guess is that this should work.